# Найти первые n документов, удовлетворяющих условию

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

В БД имеются документы подобного вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно с помощью `.findMany()` найти, допустим, 2 документа, где произведение `.techInfo.views` и `.techInfo.likes` самое большое.

Я бы мог получить все документы и с помощью цикла пройтись по ним, но тогда каждая подобная операция была бы достаточно затратна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { $project: { total: { $multiply: ['$views', '$likes'] } } },
  { $sort: { total: -1 } },
  { $limit: 2 }
])
```

Этот запрос выдаст id-шники.

По идее, с версии 4.2 вместо `$project` можно использовать `$unset` - тогда выдаст целые документы. Но у меня версия Монги ниже, поэтому проверить не могу